# How do I change ASP.NET App_Themes based on what Skin is selected in RadSkinManager?

Tags: asp.net, css, themes, telerik, skin

How do I change ASP.NET App_Themes based on what Skin is selected in RadSkinManager?

I have a RadSkinManager dropdownlist in my masterpage that allows users to select their own skin provided by Telerik Rad Controls.  I want to be able to switch my App_Theme directory so that all my other CSS and asp.net .skin files change along with the RadSkin as well.

Is there a "best practice" for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the users selected theme and set the Page.StyleSheetTheme property.

.NET profiles would work well for your described scenario. Create a UI Theme property and set the page StyleSheetTheme or Theme. Control the theme via your base page.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx for creating profile properties.

**Profile property sample:**

```
<profile>
  <properties>
    <group name="UI">
      <add name="Theme" type="System.String" defaultValue="DefaultThemeName" />
    </group>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

**Accessing the property:**

```
ProfileCommon profile = new ProfileCommon().GetProfile(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
Page.StyleSheetTheme = profile.UI.Theme;
```

Lastly, use your RadSkinManager dropdown list to set the theme for the user profile.

Comment: Do you know where I can find out more about how to use the ProfileCommon?  I can't find what namespace it's in.

Comment: @Eden Try here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.aspx)

Comment: This might help too, [http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx](http://odetocode.com/articles/440.aspx).